# SIGABRT signal when launching app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I am trying to make a window with a view controller (which i guess is like GroupBox in .Net (fix me if i'm wrong..)) and i was trying to start the application on the simulator and it threw an exception.
I am using storyboards.

my code is:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  100FMPlayer
//
//  Created by Guy Kaplan on 7/14/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Guy Kaplan. All rights reserved.
//
#import "Song.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    self.arSongsCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self.arSongsCollection;
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_arSongsCollection addObject:[[Song alloc] initWithTitle:@"Song" andArtist:@"Artist" andURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://songurl.com/song.mp3"]]];

}

@end
```

Comment: What exception? Where exactly? View controller is not groupbox. Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html, go through this roadmap first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is going to cause your trouble:

```
   _tableView.dataSource = self.arSongsCollection;
```

A dataSource is more like a delegate.  It is a protocol and is supposed to be an object (like your viewContoller) that can handle method callbacks.

You most likely want to set

```
   _tableView.dataSource = self;
```

I think you should play with some of apple's sample projects.  They helped me get going int iOS land.